# Postgresql 12 invalid binary, incorrect password (Windows 7)

Tags: postgresql, cmd, psql

I've installed the last version of psql 12, i need to be clear that i initially installed psql 10 and THEN it gave me the option to install the psql 12 version, because the psql 12 application didn't start ever when id tried, once cleared that:

id installed very normally the program, it asked a password to the database, for both psql 10 and 12 i put "admin", port 5432 again for both, and I've installed all the 4 database drivers available at the moment, now this is when the problem begins.

when i try to open the cmd and type any command of "psql" type, it inmediately opens a new line of code in blank, like I'm just not putting anything on it and pressing enter, and also, opening a new console command, psql.exe from the directory of the psql 12 to be specific, inside it, it writes the following no matter where or how i put the command "psql":

> invalid binary: "files/postgresql/12/bin/psql.exe " (yes, even with the space after the .exe)
>
> Password for user Squall322:

This is the following two cases that happens when I tried something:

If I try not writing anything, and just pressing enter, I get this error:

> Psql.exe : error: could not connect to server: fe_sendauth: no password supplied

If I try to write the password (admin) or anything other (like 1234, my username, etc) then I get:

> Psql.exe : error: could not connect to server: FATAL: la autenticación password Falló para el usuario <>

(I speak Spanish but the translation would be:

> FATAL: the authentication password failed to the user Squall322

)

In any case, the psql.exe immediately shuts down, only the cmd acts normal and does nothing, i don't know what's happening, even the environment variable path's it's set to it, both in the user and the system for both 10 and 12 (I've tried removing the 10 psql and didn't work either), then i look for the error but no help, the only mention of this was to add the path to no only the bin route, but the lib too, so now my path variable has this:

```
...;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\bin;C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\12\lib;
```

on top of the other variables of course, but none results, it's always the same.

I've tried run the cmd and the psql shell as administrator, not working either, nor even running the SQL shell (psql) inside of the archive that comes with the program, and it just runs normally until it asks for the username, then it just does the same and opens the psql.exe and asks for the password as id said above.

Just to add, the password and user are indeed the ones i put during the installation process, when I tried to use the pgAdmin 4, the program asked me for the user and password, and it worked just fine for both BD psql 10 and 12.

Comment: When you set up the password, were you crazy enough to use characters which are not in the standard ASCII set, _(characters `32..126`)_, or which are considered potentially poisonous to the command interpreter?

Comment: @Compo No, only used admin when installing the program, and things like 1234 or my own username, strange enough, it works in pgAdmin but not the console.

Answer (score 1):

The "invalid binary" error is mysterious, but the space may well be part of the problem.

The complaints about the invalid password are probably because that user doesn't exist. The default superuser that is created when the database cluster is created is traditionally called `postgres`, so your password is probably for that user.

Specify the correct user in your connection attempt:

```
psql -U postgres
```

Comment: well i've tried that and i got this after trying to put "admin" as a password for psql -U postgres on the cmd: ```psql.exe : fatal: could not find own program executable```

Comment: Looks like your installation is broken. Did you use EDB's installer? Perhaps uninstall everything, remove all files and try again. Sorry, my Windows knowledge is limited.